# /tmp files filling up with surefires files

Tags: surefire, clover

When Jenkins invokes maven build, /tmp fills with 100s of surefire839014140451157473tmp, how to explicitly redirect to another directory during the build. For clover build it fills with 100s of grover53460334580.jar? Any idea to over come this?

And any body know exact step by step to create ramdisk so I could redirect surefire stuffs into that ramdisk ? Will it save write time to hard drive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Many programs respect the `TMPDIR` (and sometimes `TMP`) environment variables. Maybe Jenkins uses APIs that respect them? Try:

```
TMPDIR=/path/to/bigger/filesystem jenkins
```

when launching Jenkins. (Or however you start it -- does it run as a daemon and have a shell-script to launch it?)

There *might* be some performance benefit to using a RAM-based filesystem -- ext3, ext4, and similar journaled filesystems will order writes to disk, and even a quick `fd=open(O_CREAT); unlink(fd);` sequence will probably require both on-disk journal updates and directory updates. (Homework: test this.) A RAM-based filesystem won't perform the journaling, and might or might not write anything to disk (depending upon which one you pick).

There are two main choices: `ramfs` is a very simple window into the kernel's caching mechanism. There is no disk-based backing for your files at all, and no memory limits. You can fill all your memory with one of these very quickly, and suffer very horrible consequences. (Almost no programs handle out-of-disk well, and the OOM-killer can't free up any of this memory.) See the Linux kernel file `Documentation/filesystems/ramfs-rootfs-initramfs.txt`.

`tmpfs` is a slight modification of `ramfs` -- you can specify an upper limit on the space it can allocate (`-o size`) *and* the page cache can swap the data to the swap partitions or swap files -- which is an excellent bonus, as your memory might be significantly better used elsewhere, such as keeping your compiler, linker, source files, and object files in core. See the Linux kernel file `Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt`.

Adding this line to your `/etc/fstab` will change `/tmp` globally:

```
tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults    0 0
```

(The default is to allow up to half your RAM to be used on the filesystem. Change the `defaults` if you need to.)

If you want to mount a `tmpfs` somewhere else, you can; maybe combine that with the `TMPDIR` environment variable from above or learn about the new shared-subtree features in `Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt` or made easy via `pam_namespace` to make it visible only to your Jenkins and child processes.